# Fit of two lines to an arbitrary set of points - NP-Hardness

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard, clustering

My problem is:

> Given $n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, I want to find a partition of these $n$ points into $k=2$ clusters. For each cluster, instead of computing the centroid as in the usual k-means problem, I construct the one-dimensional subspace (what I call a line) minimizing the sum of squared distances between the points of the cluster and the line. **So, overall, I want to find a partition such that the total sum of the squared distances between each point and the best line going through its cluster is minimized.**

For the usual k-means problem, I know that there exists a polynomial algorithm when $d$ and $k$ are fixed, and is NP-hard when one of the two is part of the input.

Related to this problem, after asking [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/160860/partition-of-two-sets-for-multi-line-fitting-np-hard) on cs.stackexchange (a particular case when  $d=2$), I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197845/how-to-fit-more-than-one-line-to-data-points) on stackoverflow where we can read this sentence in the validated answer:

> *it's well known that finding a globally optimal fit for even two lines to an arbitrary set of points is NP-Hard as it can be reduced to k-means clustering*

My question concerns the quote above: **Does anyone know a reference to this reduction claimed to be well-known?**

After lots of research and attempts to build it myself, I am not able to find such a reduction.

Comment: Could you please make the question self contained. What is the objective function you are trying to minimize.

Comment: I suggest you start by doing some research to understand the claims about NP-hardness of k-means clustering, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/153074/755, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396965/2921, https://stackoverflow.com/q/18634149/781723, then try to formulate your problem in a self-contained and precise/mathematical way (what is the objective function you are trying to minimize?), then try to come up with such a reduction.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami The objective function is the sum of the squared distances.

Comment: @D.W. I clarified my problem but my question is more about the quote claiming the reduction is well-known although I did not find any trace of it.

Comment: I don't know how to build such a reduction other, and I too am questioning whether one exists.  But perhaps understanding how k-means clustering was proven NP-hard would give some ideas for reduction strategies to prove your problem NP-hard (even if it doesn't have a direct reduction from k-means clustering).